# How do you link Facebook, Twitter, and Email Logins/Signups in Parse?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, twitter, parse-platform, parseui

I'm using the ParseUI framework and have enabled the emailAsUsername property of the LogInController. However, I'm a bit concerned about the following scenarios:

1) users signs up wtih facebook
2) user logs out
3) user logs in with email (don't think this is possible because there is no password he originally entered) OR user logs in with twitter

OR

1) user signs up wtih email and password
2) user logs out
3) user logs in with facebook.

In both scenarios above, parse will not recognize that the same user has logged in and will create two PFUser entries. I see the following code in parse docs, but it's not clear to me if it's appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

```
[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
    }
}];
```

In short, my question is how is it possible to link email, facebook, and twitter accounts so that there is only one PFUser for all three? This would allow access to the same user associated app data.

Thank you
Jas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as you expect.

The `linkUser:` methods will allow your users to log back in using Twitter or Facebook even if they originally signed up using email (provided that they allow the link which works exactly like a login).

You can also set an email and a password later if you user logged in with Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: Ok, so the flow would be sign up with email/password and then the app, and then i'd call linkUser. But this would take them out of the app and present a facebook authorization?

OR

User signs up with facebook, and i prompt them for e-mail and password?

there is no way to do this without the 'extra' user interaction?

Comment: Consider the linkUser: functionality identical to the login: functionality except that instead of creating a new user, it merges the auth data with the existing user. So yes, linking an existing user would take that user out of the app (or not if there is a Facebook system account). Obviously, there is no way to avoid it, this is the way the Facebook login/link flow works. If you have a Facebook logged in user, yes you have to prompt at least for a password (you can use the email from Facebook if you request it when you link). In a word : no way to do this without the 'extra' user interaction.